# Get count of rows in Paquet file in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, parquet

I am writing a Powershell script that compares the number of rows in 2 parquet files that are created each hour to monitor the number of rows etc.

I have found the [Parquet.NET](https://github.com/elastacloud/parquet-dotnet) project, but since all I want to do is query the count of rows, I wonder if this is overkill. Is there a module for parquet?